# Sylius VAT based on delivery address

Tags: sylius

I'm trying to evaluate Sylius as a replacement for an existing shop system. However, I was unable to find an option on the demo system where Sylius calculates VAT based on the user's delivery address. Additionally, the VAT is not displayed in the frontend. How can this be configured?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show product based on address in frontend that would be little tricky, I think best way is to create custom channel. Then detect user location and show proper channel (maybe subdomain) - in any case for this you need to know user location. We resolved this in one project with asking him at the begining then store to cookie or account if he is logged in.

Regarding tax based on address in checkout that is possible, tax is very flexible and it is related to type of products (category) or location, so you can create different tax for different countries and this will be updated in checkout process after user decide where to deliver it.